TypeError in nodemon server with Typescript file extension
TS file!
import express, {Request, Response} from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import 'dotenv/config';

const app = express();
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(cors())

app.get("/api/test", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.json({ message: "hello from express endpoint!"})
});

app.listen(7000, ()=>{
    console.log("server runnig on localhost 7000");
});


TypeError: Unknown file extension ".ts" for D:\projects of frontend\My Project\MERN PROJECT\backend\src\index.ts
at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:160:9)
at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:203:36)
at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:143:22)
at async ModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:396:7)
at async ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:278:45)
at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:78:21) {
code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

installed and configured all of required extensions and packages..
npm packages --> npm i cors node express mongodb moongoose
using ---save-dev method on--> npm i  @types/cors @types/express @types/node typescript ts-node nodemon --save-dev
but fornately while running my file with -->  npm run dev
the error received
the max upto solution i've reached is i've updated my package.json file with "type: module", updated a "scripts": "dev": "nodemon --watch \"src/**/*.ts\" --exec \"ts-node src/index.ts\" --delay 2", "start": "ts-node src/index.ts"
but not working at all!!!
kindly if you have any sort of solution to deal with this errror  response back!!!!
thank you!

Change to "dev": "nodemon --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --exec 'ts-node' src/index.ts"
Share package.json and tsconfig.json for more help.
In general:
compilerOptions should be set correctly to fit ts-node and your project, the below should be sufficient:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

